# Does the Naruto: Ultimate Ninja Storm series miss any of the Manga's plot?

Tags: naruto

So i watched a review on Naruto: Ultimate Ninja Storm 4 on Good Game SP. Hex and Bajo said it was the last in the series which probably finishes where the manga finishes.

I have been wondering if the Naruto: Ultimate Ninja Storm series contains all the manga plot and also if they include any of the fillers from the anime series (considering the anime hasn't caught up to the end of the Manga)

Comment: All of them with simplified animation with over-the-top original jutsu.

Comment: I have to agree mostly with Dragon and Namikaze. In general, the games cover all the major plot points, though they add extra fights and misc scenes, and noticeably alter the dialog, but all the main points/highlights of the manga are usually there.

Comment: Well number three ends with a FMA size case of catching up to the source material.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a Naruto wiki which has a lot of info worth checking, but I'm not sure if what you want is in there. I have played the game completely and have read all the manga and I could not find any missing bits apart from that they would (this happens in every Naruto game) make the story a bit shorter and sometimes just a tiny bit, they would take some speech out. That's all I know but I could be wrong. I shouldn't though, I'm pretty sure I remembered it right.

Answer (score 1):

The game franchise did cover the whole story, but not in detail. What I'm trying to say is, they basically give a small flashback for each story that led to each problem that needs to be solved by Naruto and his friends. That's how the storytelling works in the game.